# PCL: Using only one coordinate, how to find remaining two coordinates of a point or all the possible points?

Tags: c++, computer-vision, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

Let say I have a point cloud and I know only one coordinate of a point. For example, using `pcl::getMinMax3D()` method, I have 3 minimum values and 3 maximum values.

However, the problem is it's not necessary that minimum X, Y, or Z value would correspond to the same point! It's very likely that those values can correspond to three different points. Basically, the method returns minimum (& maximum) values, not a point(s).

So, using one minimum or maximum value for any coordinate, I want to find the remaining two coordinates i.e. eventually a valid point or multiple points. How can I do this using `PCL` (Point Cloud Library)?

Answer (score 1):

Just use the STL algorithm:

```
auto point = std::min_element(cloud.begin(), cloud.end(), [](auto& p1, auto& p2) {return p1.x < p2.x; });
```

Comment: Thank you for posting the solution but it's not working! It's giving me this error: `error: ‘const class __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<pcl::PointXYZ*, std::vector<pcl::PointXYZ, Eigen::aligned_allocator<pcl::PointXYZ> > >’ has no member named ‘x’
     auto point = std::min(cloud->begin(), cloud->end(), [](auto& p1, auto& p2) { return p1.x < p2.x; });` and this one `/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_algobase.h:246:17: error: could not convert ‘__comp.main()::<lambda(auto:1&, auto:2&)>((* & __b), (* & __a))’ from ‘void’ to ‘bool’
       if (__comp(__b, __a))
           ~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~`

Comment: I even tried replacing `auto` with `pcl::PointXYZ` i.e. `auto point = std::min(cloud->begin(), cloud->end(), [](pcl::PointXYZ& p1, pcl::PointXYZ& p2) { return p1.x < p2.x; });` but it's still giving the 2nd error: `...algobase.h:246:17: error: no match for call to ‘(main()::<lambda(pcl::PointXYZ&, pcl::PointXYZ&)>) (const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<pcl::PointXYZ*, std::vector<pcl::PointXYZ, Eigen::aligned_allocator<pcl::PointXYZ> > >&, const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<pcl::PointXYZ*, std::vector<pcl::PointXYZ, Eigen::aligned_allocator<pcl::PointXYZ> > >&)’
       if (__comp(__b, __a))`

Comment: Try p1->x and p2->x. p1 and p2 are iterators to a point, the value of which can be queried with the -> operator. Sorry for the confusion, I updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks again for correcting your answer. This time, it gets compiled. However, the final answer it gives is wrong. For example, for `pt1(8.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)`, `pt2(0.0f, 6.0f, 0.0f)`, `pt3(0.0f, 0.0f, 4.0f)`, & `pt4(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f)` of type `pcl::PointXYZ`, the output I"m getting for `std::cout << (*point)` is `(0,0,1.45875e-42)`! Ideally, it should be either `(0,6,0)` or `(0,0,4)`

Comment: Also, how did you decide it should be `p1->x` & `p2->x` rather than `p1.x` & `p2.x`? If possible, could you please elaborate on that as well? I'm super confused, right now! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hello Milan, I am sorry for the confusion. I mixed up std::min and std::min_element. std::min_element allows operations on ranges. The std::min_element version will work with . since the elements that are passed to the comparison function are the elements themselves. Take a look at the reference: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element